# ConversationIndex cannot be found on Office.context.mailbox.item

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

When using `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages` Graph API

I can see that there's a conversationIndex

[image]

But when using Office.context.mailbox.item on MessageReadCommandSurface extension point
It supposed the conversationIndex must be on the Office.context.mailbox.item since the mail was already created.

[image]

Ive tried email with replies and no replies.

Please guide on me. Thank you